# latexmk vs pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex x 2

Tags: texlive, latexmk

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the following two compilation methods:

1. latexmk
2. pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex` x 2

Is one method faster than the other and which should be preferred on a modern texlive distribution.

Comment: I assume the "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex x 2 " comes from your editor's interface? Which editor is that? If it really blindly runs pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, then `latexmk` is *usually* a bit cleverer than that, but some editors do some log parsing and magic re-run detection themselves...

Comment: I personally use `latexmk` quite often because I can just press compile once and usually get a good result quickly. There are (pathological) situations where `latexmk` executes superfluous LaTeX runs, but there is (almost?) no way to filter those out and those situations don't really occur naturally. Very rarely does it happen that `latexmk` gets stuck between LaTeX and Biber runs due to a nasty error. But even then it is usually enough to remove the temporary files and try again (and I'm not even sure if a predefined compilation chain would fare any better).

Comment: Yes pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex x 2 essentially just runs those in order.  See https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-recipes

Comment: There are times when you might need more than 2 final runs of pdflatex and latexmk takes care of that for you. If you really use bibtex latexmk sometimes does an extra bibtex run. If you use the biblatex package with biber latexmk automatically knows that it should run biber rather than bibtex. Using latexmkrc (platexmkrc with TeXShop’s latexmk engines) files (which are written in Perl) you can set up latexmk to automatically do many tasks needed with various packages.

Comment: latexmk will be much faster if not all four commands are necessary - if all four commands are necessary, latexmk will only be a tiny bit slower. In the long run latexmk will save a lot of time

Comment: Same puzzel.....